# Java - Unexpected break while taking input for a character

Tags: java

New to Java, having trouble figuring out why this isn't working, it stops unexpectedly half way through taking user inputs.  I've commented where it breaks.  Error message : 
"Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException"

Can anybody help?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BasicInput {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);

      //Initializations
      int userInt = 0;
      double userDouble = 0.0;
      String userString = "";
      char character = '?';

      //Take User Input
      System.out.println("Enter integer: ");
      userInt = scnr.nextInt();
      System.out.println("Enter double: ");
      userDouble = scnr.nextInt();

      /* ERROR OCCURS HERE */

      System.out.println("Enter character: ");
      character = scnr.next().charAt(0);
      System.out.println("Enter string: ");
      userString = scnr.next();

      //Print User Input

      System.out.println(userString);
      System.out.print(character);
      System.out.print(userDouble);
      System.out.print(userInt);

      //Cast double to an integer
      int userInt2 = 0;
      userInt2 = (int)userDouble;
      System.out.print(userInt2);

      return;
   }
}
```

Comment: You're asking for a double but your Scanner is getting `scnr.nextInt()` -- do you see a problem with this? Wouldn't `scnr.nextDouble()` be more appropriate?

Comment: Yes! Works perfectly now.  I am more familiar with Python (although still beginner level with that) so scanner has proven to be confusing for me.  Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

Reading int instead of a double, change it to double like below

```
   //Take User Input
  System.out.println("Enter integer: ");
  userInt = scnr.nextInt();
  System.out.println("Enter double: ");
  userDouble = scnr.nextDouble();
```

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs when you assign the value of scnr.nextInt() to userDouble. You should use scnr.nextDouble(). Also when you type the double use "," as separator, not "." 
It should work :)